# MIPS: Integer Multiplication and Division

Tags: mips

So I'm building a calculator program in MIPS and I'm trying to write the multiply and divide functions.

Currently I read in the integers in a loop like so:

```
li $v0, 5
syscall
```

and then eventually call my functions `multi` and `divi`depending on which action the user wants to do.

So assuming I have the integers in `$a0` and `$a1`, what would be a clean way to multiply `$a0` by `$a1` and/or divide `$a0` by `$a1`? I've been looking around online but I can't find a clean and easy way to do this, because I have to send the resulting answer back in `$v0`

Comment: Is there something wrong with the `MULT` instruction?

Comment: Why not just branch on whether it's a multiply or a divide?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To multiply, use `mult` for signed multiplication and `multu` for unsigned multiplication. Note that the result of the multiplication of two 32-bit numbers yields a 64-number. If you want the result back in `$v0` that means that you assume the result will fit in 32 bits.

The 32 most significant bits will be held in the `HI` special register (accessible by `mfhi` instruction) and the 32 least significant bits will be held in the `LO` special register (accessible by the `mflo` instruction):

E.g.:

```
li $a0, 5
li $a1, 3
mult $a0, $a1
mfhi $a2 # 32 most significant bits of multiplication to $a2
mflo $v0 # 32 least significant bits of multiplication to $v0
```

To divide, use `div` for signed division and `divu` for unsigned division. In this case, the `HI` special register will hold the remainder and the `LO` special register will hold the quotient of the division.

E.g.:

```
div $a0, $a1
mfhi $a2 # remainder to $a2
mflo $v0 # quotient to $v0
```

Comment: After mult. How do you merge the two (hi and lo) into one result? In case I know the result will fit in a 32 bit register?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou: If you already know the result fits in 32 bit you can just retrieve the low significant bits using `mflo`

Comment: Hello, so the multiplication result is stored in mfhi and mflo depending on the bit size?

Comment: @Leonard: The multiplication of two 32-bit numbers yields a 64-bit number. Both registers are always used to store the result. The 32 high significant binary digits of the multiplication are stored in "HI" and the the 32 less significant ones in "LO". You can the retrieve them using `mfhi` and `mflo` respectively. If you only know in advance the multiplication fits in 32 bits you can just retrieve the "LO" part (that is, use `mflo`) and disregard the "HI" part.

Comment: @gusbro You are much more helpful than 100% of the materials I've seen regarding this. Thanks!