# How to get current time in seconds in MIPS Assembly Language?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I am trying to get the current time in MIPS in hour:minute:second format. I know that using syscall 30 will place the total number of milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970 into registers $a1 and $a0, but I dont know how to add the registers together and divide by 1000 to get the total number of seconds. I believe the rest should be easy after that.

Thank you!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050338/mips-integer-multiplication-and-division.  You can either use the hardware 32b / 32b => 32b division instruction to build an extended-precision divide by 1000, or you can use the fixed-point multiplicative inverse.  You'll have to build a 64b x 1000 => 128b multiply out of 32-bit multiplies, but on hardware with multiply *much* faster than divide it could be worth it.  (gcc just calls a libgcc.a helper function for `int div_by_1000(long long millis) {
    return millis / 1000;
}`: https://godbolt.org/g/MR6h6d; you could look at its src.)

Answer (score 3):

**Dividing 64-bit number**

Since MIPS, as emulated on MARS, doesn't support 64 ÷ 32 ⇒ 64 divisions<sup>1</sup> we need to implement our own *multi-word* division.
The book *Hacker delight* as a [chapter](https://books.google.it/books?id=VicPJYM0I5QC&lpg=PA184&ots=2o_ULWrt1t&dq=multiword%20division&pg=PA184#v=onepage&q&f=false) on it, based mostly on *The Art of computer programming* by Knuth.

The idea is very simple in principle: Consider a 64-bit number as a two digits number, each digit is 32-bit (so the base of this number is 2<sup>32</sup>), and perform the grade-school digit-by-digit division.

Let's tackle this idea down with a base-10 example: consider 53 / 2.
We can calculate the result by dividing 5 by 2, giving a result *m<sub>1</sub>* of 2 and a remainder *r<sub>1</sub>* of 1.
*m<sub>1</sub>* is the first digit of the result (the most significant one).
Then we "drop" the 3 in 53 to get the number 13, this is *r<sub>1</sub>* * 10 + 3.
Again we do 13 / 2 to get *m<sub>0</sub>* = 6 and *r<sub>0</sub>* = 1.
The result is thus 26 (with remainder 1).

We adopt the same approach, the only difference being that we deal with digits that range from 0 to 2<sup>32</sup> - 1.
So a 64-bit number, like the one returned by the time syscall, is seen as a two digits number: the lest significant one (the rightmost) is in `$a0`, the other one in `$a1`.
For example, the number 0x15EF18933B1 is seen as

```
 Digit 1  Digit 0
 0x15E    0xF18933B1
```

The algorithm we are looking for is then just a loop where we "add" the last remainder to the current digit, we divide by the divisor to get the current digit of the result and the remainder to use in the next step.
Note that by "add" we mean "to add with weight", the remainder *r<sub>i</sub>* is not added to the current digit *n<sub>i</sub>*, it is *scaled* by the base and then added (this is exactly what we did earlier, we did 1*10+3, not 1+3).
I'm not going to explain the algorithm in depth as it is widely available online.

One very important thing to note is that we are not actually getting anywhere.
Due to the scaling of the current remainder, we still need to perform a 64 ÷ 32 ⇒ 64 division (like for the decimal case, 13 / 2 is not easier than 53 / 2!).
The difference is that we know that the number is at most of two digits.

To untangle this circular argument, we need to scale down to a 32 ÷ 16 ⇒ 32 division.
MIPS supports 32 ÷ 32 ⇒ 32, by limiting our divisor to at most 65535 we get what we wanted.
So the algorithm works with half-word of 16 bits, a 64-bit number is seen as a 4 digits number then.

The code is

```
#Input
#   a0:a1 = N = DCBA
#   a2    = K (16-bit)

#Output
#   a0:a1 = quotient
#   hi    = reminder
div64x16:
 subu $sp, $sp, 16

 sw $a0, ($sp)
 sw $a1, 4($sp)

 add $t0, $sp, 8     # Pointer to digits (N)
 add $t3, $sp, 16    # Pointer to result (M)
 xor $t1, $t1, $t1   # Remainder

loop: 
  subu $t3, $t3, 2
  subu $t0, $t0, 2

  sll $t1, $t1, 16   # t1 = R * 65536
  lhu $t2, ($t0)     # t2 = N[i]
  addu $t2, $t2, $t1 # t2 = N[i] + R * 65536

  div $t2, $a2

  mflo $t1           # t1 = (N[i] + R * 65536) / K
  sh $t1, ($t3)      # M[i] = (N[i] + R * 65536) / K

  mfhi $t1           # t1 =  (N[i] + R * 65536) % K

bne $t0, $sp, loop

 mthi $t1

 lw $a0, 8($sp) 
 lw $a1, 12($sp)

 addu $sp, $sp, 16
 jr $ra
```

The input arguments are in `a0:a1` (the 64-bit dividend, low word in `a0`) and `a2` (the divisor).
The result is in `a0:a1` (quotient) and `hi` (remainder).

**Note** that there is a limitation on the divisor: it must be of 16 bits in size.
This simplifies the division algorithm a lot but requires some workaround when computing the time of day.

**Computing the time of day**

Given the ms from the Unix epoch (1st January 1970) to get the time of day one divides by 1000 * 3600 * 24 and takes the remainder.
However, 1000 * 3600 * 24 doesn't fit 16 bits. We can do it with three division but then we will need to combine the remainders.

There is a slightly simpler and more intuitive approach.
First, we get rid of the ms. We don't need ms accuracy in the time of day, so we can discard the remainder altogether.

```
li $v0, 30
syscall

#a0:a1 = ms since epoch

li $a2, 1000 
jal div64x16  

#a0:a1 = seconds since epoch
```

Now we'd need to divide by 3600 * 24 = 86400 but we can't.
A nice trick is to divide by 3600 * 12 = 43200 (that fits 16 bits), this gives us the number of *half-days* (let's call it *hh*) and the remainder gives us the number of second far into the half-day (call it *hs*).
Since there are 43200 seconds in an half-day, time can at most be 11:59:59.
We don't know if 2:0:0 is 2pm or 2am, we need to check if *hh* is odd or even to know, if *hh* is even then we are in the first half-day of a day and the time is right, otherwise we are in the second half-day and we add 43200 (the seconds in an half-day) to *hs*.
This converts seconds in half-days to seconds in *days*.

```
#a0:a1 = seconds since epoch

li $a2, 43200
jal div64x16

#a0:a1 = half-days since epoch
#hi = seconds in half-day

mfhi $s0              #Seconds in the half-day

andi $a0, $a0, 1      #a1 = 1 if odd half-day number (otherwise 0)
ror $a0, $a0, 1       #a1 < 0 if odd half-day number (otherwise 0)
sra $a0, $a0, 31      #a1 = 0xffffffff if odd half-day number (otherwise 0)
andi $a0, $a0, 43200  #a1 = 43200  if odd half-day number (otherwise 0)

add $s0, $s0, $a0     #s0 = seconds in the day
```

Once one has the seconds in the day (a 32-bit number) the rest is easy.

```
li $t0, 3600
div $s0, $t0         
mflo $s0              #s0 = Hour

mfhi $t1 
li $t0, 60 
div $t1, $t0 
mflo $s1              #s1 = Minute
mfhi $s2              #s2 = Second

#Print the time
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s0
syscall 

li $v0, 4
la $a0, sep
syscall 

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s1
syscall 

li $v0, 4
la $a0, sep
syscall 

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s2
syscall  


#Exit
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

**Note** The time system call use the Java `new Date().getTime()` value, this is the current time in the GMT timezone. Unless you live in that timezone, the hours will be different.

---

<sup>1</sup> This notation denotes a 64-bit dividend, a 32-bit divisor and a 64-bit result.